# same data produces different pandas plot

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I created a graph using DOGE crypto data:

```
import pandas as pd
import csv

df2 = pd.read_csv("https://raw.githubusercontent.com/peoplecure/pandoras-box/master/doge.csv")
plt.plot(df2['begins_at'], df2['open_price'])
plt.show()
```

[image]

Above graph looks fine. But, when I try to create a graph using another method with the exact same data, the graph looks totally off

```
from pandas import DataFrame

df = DataFrame (DOGE_data)
plt.plot(df['begins_at'], df['open_price'])
plt.show()
```

[image]

Regrettably, I don't have a way to share the data in the second method. However, data used in the first graph was created by `df`. I was hoping if anyone has any idea what may be going on here.

Comment: Please share the code from where you are calculating/getting 'DOGE_data'

Answer (score 0):

The messed up y-axis could be the hint: Usually, *with numerical data*, there would be 4-12 y-axis label ticks and markers. Then, usually, with non-numerical data, there is one tick for each "category".

Check the data type of y-data in the second dataset: `df['open_price'].dtype`